# How add some source code in a UWP installed app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, uwp, taco

I developed an UWP app with Cordova and IndexedDB storage. I need recover some information stored in the indexed database adding a new action to source code.

I got access to the app path at `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/com.mi.app_xxxxx/` inside the `www` directory I added the new action code. When I start the app it crashes without error messages.

Comment: Could you share a simple sample about this?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT example about the UWP app?

Comment: Sure, the sample that could reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not manually tamper with the files in the app install location (`C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/` folder). This is a security measure and if any app file is changed in this folder, the system will not allow the app to be launched. The reason for this is that otherwise, anyone could access your app and for example replace some library with malicious executable or crack a licensed app.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Zikmund I found the IndexedDB file located at %AppData%/../Local/Packages/[miapp]/AppData/Indexed DB/ and after some tests the database can be copy and use in another app.

Comment: Yes, that is the application data directory and you can freely edit it. Only the install location is protected. Happy coding!